# What happens if I send integers to a BigQuery field "string"?

Tags: google-bigquery

One of the columns I send (in my code) to BigQuery is integers. I added the columns to BigQuery and I was too fast and added them as type string.

Will they be automatically converted? Or will the data be totally corrupted (= I cannot trust at all the resulting string)?

Answer (score 1):

Data shouldn't be automatically converted as this would destroy the purpose of having a table schema.

What I've seen people doing is saving a whole json line as string and then processing this string inside of BigQuery. Other than that, if you try to save values not correspondent to the field schema definition, you should see an error being thrown, like so:

[image]

If you need to change a table schema's definition, you can check [this tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/tables#updateschema) on updating a table schema.

Answer (score 1):

Actually BigQuery converted automatically the integers that I have sent it to string, so my table populates ok